# OPA Bundle in Azure Storage location

Tags: azure, open-policy-agent

1. We have OPA Bundles(.tar file) and stored in Azure storage location(i.e Container).
2. Azure storage location access level is private.

How can we define OPA configuration file to access the OPA bundle which is in Azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possible bundle configuration would look something like this:

```yaml
services:
  azure:
    url: https://my-azure.endpoint.com/v1

bundles:
  authz:
    service: azure
    resource: bundles/authz.tar.gz
```

If you need Azure specific authentication options, there's an open ticket (with some alternatives provided) [here](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/issues/2964).